# Visual Studio lost all References

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sdl, project

I worked for a long time on my C++ Projekt in Visual Studio 2017.

Now i tried to compile my project and it shows me over 180 build errors. It seems like he lost all references to my classes.

Base class are undefined / methods not found etc.

The Inlude part itself shows no error, so it feels like he is able to finde the files.

[image]
He also highlighted my classes in the code so i think he should be able to find everything.

Dose someone know how to fix this bug?

OUTPUT

```
1>------ Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: SDL Project Template1, Konfiguration: Debug Win32 ------
1>colliderWall.cpp
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gamecamera.h(9): error C2504: "GameObject": Basisklasse undefiniert
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gamecamera.h(12): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "reffer"
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gamecamera.h(12): error C2535: "gameCamera::gameCamera(void)": Memberfunktion bereits definiert oder deklariert
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gamecamera.h(11): note: Siehe Deklaration von "gameCamera::gameCamera"
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gamecamera.h(19): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "GameObject"
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gamecamera.h(15): error C3668: "gameCamera::logik": Die Methode mit dem Überschreibungsspezifizierer "override" hat keine Basisklassenmethoden überschrieben.
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gamecamera.h(16): error C3668: "gameCamera::draw": Die Methode mit dem Überschreibungsspezifizierer "override" hat keine Basisklassenmethoden überschrieben.
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gamecamera.h(17): error C3668: "gameCamera::save": Die Methode mit dem Überschreibungsspezifizierer "override" hat keine Basisklassenmethoden überschrieben.
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gamecamera.h(18): error C3668: "gameCamera::load": Die Methode mit dem Überschreibungsspezifizierer "override" hat keine Basisklassenmethoden überschrieben.
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gamecamera.h(19): error C3668: "gameCamera::onCollide": Die Methode mit dem Überschreibungsspezifizierer "override" hat keine Basisklassenmethoden überschrieben.
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gameobject.h(14): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "reffer"
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gameobject.h(14): error C2535: "GameObject::GameObject(void)": Memberfunktion bereits definiert oder deklariert
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gameobject.h(13): note: Siehe Deklaration von "GameObject::GameObject"
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gameobject.h(22): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ";" vor "*"
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gameobject.h(22): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gameobject.h(22): error C2238: Unerwartete(s) Token vor ";"
1>h:\15. engine\sdl project template1\sdl project template1\gameobject.h(23): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ";" vor "*
```

gameCamera.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Transform.h"
#include "SpriteRenderer.h"
#include "reffer.h"
#include "GameObject.h"

class gameCamera :
    public GameObject
{
public:
    gameCamera();
    gameCamera(reffer* _refObj);
    ~gameCamera();

    void logik()    override;
    void draw()     override;
    void save()     override;
    void load()     override;
    void onCollide(GameObject * coll) override;
};
```

Comment: There is no such thing as reference to class, not on IDE level. IDE and compiler are separate programs. There is something wrong with code or with project settings, e.g. you should be sure that you included right header files and their location is in search path of compiler. This question is subject-less without any code and/or compiler's command line  and error text to show

Comment: What's the **first** compiler error. Post the complete error message. All the other errors probably follow from that one.

Comment: added a screen.

Comment: Unresolved references are due to link errors. This can have various reasons. Mostly, these are broken dependencies. E.g. broken dependencies of projects -> missing libraries. Sometimes, configurations (platform, debug/release) are mixed accidentally. Manually configured link libraries (or paths) are lost. Sometimes, it is even caused by source code. E.g. if signature of a function varies in header and source (even slightly), this doesn't yield a compiler error but an unresolved reference. (Implementation is unrelated to prototype what's not a compiler error. Such mistakes are hard to find.)

Comment: @MThiele It's very important that you show the first error. Your screenshot is not doing that.

Comment: @MThiele The first errro I can see is in file gameobject.h on line 14, but there could be others that I can't see.

Comment: It does, "GameObject" baseclass is undefined

Comment: Please look in the "Ausgabe" tab at the bottom and add the first few error messages that show up there to your question.

Comment: @MThiele No it doesn't

Comment: Please post error messages (and code) as text, not as images. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @MThiele Visual Studio rearranges the order of error messages (its a really unhelpful feature). You need to show the first error message and you need to open a different window to do that.

Comment: @MThiele I don't speak German but do what Max Langhof says

Comment: @john "Ausgabe" == "Output" ;-)

Comment: Please, don't expose textual info as image. Please, copy/paste text as text. (In my case, company security policy prevents me to open any image from imgur. So, I've no idea what you exposed and I'm curios...)

Comment: Added the OUPUT - Same Error as in the PIC. And many more.

Comment: Added the gameCamera.h

Comment: The wonders of missing header guards can cause situation like these. Make sure all your custom header files are properly written with guards.

Comment: @Lundin I can't imagine a situation where missing include guards would lead to the first error being an undefined class... Infinite recursive inclusion or re-definitions, yes. But missing class definition?

Comment: @MaxLanghof That helps the infinite circular inclusion to propagate, compiler simply runs out of recursion (strange that MS never bothered to add code that detects it). Simply an UB _in_ compiler may happen or it stops recursion at state where one of definition still is required. I saw that with older compilers at least

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I would expect any compiler (even MSVC) to at least notify you when "running out of recursion". Indeed, my VS2015 intellisense already barks at recursive includes, and the compiler shouts `fatal error C1014: too many include files: depth = 1024` before getting anywhere. I believe you that older compilers may have failed at this, but the VS2017 one should not be one of them.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Even 2005 could do that. Already had C1014. Still I was meeting cases when it don't. No idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feels like you have circular include dependencies. Try moving `#include "SpriteRenderer.h"`, `#include "Transform.h"` and `#include "reffer.h"` into `gameCamera.cpp` and add a forward declaration for `reffer`. Then the only include in `gameCamera.h` is `GameObject.h` and things will probably work.

In general, it is good practice to keep the number of headers you include in a given header to the bare minimum - include them in the `.cpp` instead if you need to, but otherwise stick with forward declarations as much as possible. It primarily reduces compile times (and re-compile avalanches) but it can also help in avoiding or easing diagnosis of cases like yours.

Comment: Sometimes, other simple errors can cause a similar avalanche of errors. I recognized terrible things when I forgot to close namespaces in a header... (Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't mention this error at all. Strictly speaking, it is not an error concerning C++. But every file which `#include`s that broken header, will cause tons of errors. Hence, it's a bit difficult to find such issues. IMHO, best works to remember "What did I change last?".)

Comment: The first time you get this problem it's unnerving. Suddenly you go from being in control to not understanding anything.

Comment: @Scheff Good point. But even if my hunch is wrong here, it will probably help with isolating the issue.

Comment: circular include dependencies was right. Thanks!